# How does the object-detection methods really work?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, conv-neural-network

I'm in a group project in school and we are using the [tensorflow object-detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) in a *Raspberry Pi 3* but do not know how the *object detection methods*, **SSD** (single shot detector) and **CNN** (convolutional neural network), works underneath.

Can someone give a simple yet non-trivial explanation on how SSD and CNN works and recommendations on possible factors that might optimize the speed of the object detection methods.

Please link us to good articles if you know any!

Comment: As you're question is not primarily about a coding problem, but about the theory underneath, this question is best asked on the [Cross Validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Moreover, I don't think a subject as broad as object detection can be summarized in one answer. Good luck on your project!

Comment: Check https://leonardoaraujosantos.gitbooks.io/artificial-inteligence/content/single-shot-detectors.html for some details

Comment: CNN is the basics - got established in the 1990's. There are many great explanations on how it works - one of my favorites is in the book by Aurélien Géron. Start with that or something similar. Don't even bother looking at SSD until you understand CNN's, pooling, softmax, etc.

Comment: SSD is a modern technique that builds on many many refinements over the years. This paper (that comes from the object detection site you linked to) - goes into it. https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.10012  - to understand SSD you need to go through the evolution of the architectures that is described in that paper, all derivatives of 20-30 years of CNN development.